# Display: none está apagando onde não deveria

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Ao utilizar o `Display: none` para excluir o `h2` (que contém o título) no `@media`, ele acaba excluindo aas opções presentes no menu, mesmo sendo o `h2` pertencente ao `id: navbar` e o menu ao `id: navbar-list`. Em resumo, quero tirar o `h2` sem perder a navbar-list para deixar o site mais agradável nos smartphones utilizando o `@media`, com `max-width:450px` ou afins... fiz os testes pelo próprio Chrome.
Segue os códigos html e css completos.

```css
/*Reset*/
body,
p,
h1,
h2,
input,
textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*navbar*/
#navbar {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 85px;
}

#navbar h2,
#navbar ul,
#navbar-list li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar h2 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    color: #ac0582;
}

#navbar img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#navbar ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transform: translateY(-400%);
}

#navbar li {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

#navbar-list li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#navbar-list li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid white;
}

/*Fim navbar*/
/*Banner*/
#main-banner {
    height: 80vh;
    background-image: url('Imgs/p3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 18vh;
}

#banner-infos {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#banner-infos img {
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 22%;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#banner-infos p {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

/*Fim Banner*/
/*About*/
#about-section {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 350px;
}

#about-section h2 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#about-section p {
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}

/*About*/
/*Skills*/
#skills-section {
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 85%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1.7px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#skills-section .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.skills-container {
    flex: 1 1 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 25px;
    ;
}

.central {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.skills-container h3 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.skills-container img {
    height: 105px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    border-right: 5.5px solid #000000;
}

.skills-container .subtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.skills-container p {
    line-height: 25px;
}

/*Fim Skills*/


/*Products*/
#products-section {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#products-section h2 {
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#products-section p {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#products-section a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(220 151 19);
}

.product-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-box {
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.pr1 {
    background-image: url('Imgs/p1.jpg');
}

.pr2 {
    background-image: url('Imgs/p2.jpg');
}

.pr3 {
    background-image: url('Imgs/p6.jpg');
}

/*Fim Products*/
/*Footer*/
footer {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

footer img {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px 0;

}

footer p {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

footer form {
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

footer input,
footer textarea {
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

footer .desenvolvedor {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Fim Footer*/

/*Responsivo para smartphone*/
@media (max-width:450px) {

    p,
    input,
    textarea,
    #navbar-list li a {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    #navbar h2 {
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        display: none;
    }

    #navbar ul {
        margin-top: 1.1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>The Gallery Art - XXI</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-widht, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilo.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <header id="navbar">
      <img src="Imgs/Logo.png" alt="#" />
      <h2>Esse texto tem que sumir no smartphone</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul id="navbar-list">
        <!--Essas três opções tem que continuar-->
          <li><a href="##">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="##">Conteúdo</a></li>
          <li><a href="##">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Fim Navbar-->

    <main>
      <!--Banner-->
      <div id="main-banner">
        <div id="banner-infos">
          <h1>X X I</h1>
          <img src="Imgs/Logo.png" alt="#" />
          <p>
            The risk of a wrong decision is preferable to the terror of
            indecision....
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Fim Banner-->
      <!--About-->
      <section id="about-section">
        <h2>The 21st Century Digital Art Revolution</h2>
        <p>
          The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced
          below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de
          Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their
          exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914
          translation by H. Rackham.
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--Fim About-->
    </main>

    <!--Skills-->
    <section id="skills-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills-container">
          <img src="Imgs/1.png" alt="Img1" />
          <h3>Teste</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry.
          </p>
          <p class="subtitle">Zeus</p>
          <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
          </p>

          <p class="subtitle">Hera</p>
          <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-container">
          <img src="Imgs/2.png" alt="Img2" />
          <h3>The Concept</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Poseidon</p>
          <p>
            Curabitur urna leo, malesuada at dolor et, interdum convallis
            lectus.
          </p>
          <p class="subtitle">Atena</p>
          <p>Ut aliquam facilisis nibh vitae convallis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-container">
          <img src="Imgs/3.png" alt="Img3" />
          <h3>The Purpouse</h3>
          <p>Ut vulputate neque ut lacus suscipit ullamcorper</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Ares</p>
          <p>Ut nunc mi, pharetra eu eleifend vitae, gravida ac lacus.</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Apolo</p>
          <p>Nulla interdum lectus quam, malesuada luctus ex viverra eu.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--Fim Skills-->
    <!--Products-->
    <section id="products-section">
      <h2>Artwork of the week</h2>
      <p>
        Check out some of the featured artworks, or click
        <a href="#">here</a> and see them all.
      </p>
      <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-box pr1"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr2"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-box pr2"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr3"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr1"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--Fim Products-->
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <p>We await your message :)</p>
      <img src="Imgs/Logo.png" alt="#" />

      <form action="" method="">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <!--INPUT PARA NUM DE TELEFONE-->
        <input type="tel" name="number" placeholder="Number" />
        <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Done!" />
      </form>
      <p>Developer <span class="desenvolvedor">Gustavo Lopes - 2021</span></p>
    </footer>
    <!--Fim Footer-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O menu não está sendo escondido. Ele está sendo deslocado pra baixo (porque não cabe na largura da tela) e ficando sobre a área branca, e com isso fica sem ser visto por ser branco também, mas está lá.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! notei isso também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que você estava dando um `transforme: translate(-400%)` no ul

Segue o seu código corrigido:
(coloquei o @media para 991px para poder testar aqui)

```css
/*Reset*/
body,
p,
h1,
h2,
input,
textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*navbar*/
#navbar {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 85px;
}

#navbar h2,
#navbar ul,
#navbar-list li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar h2 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    color: #ac0582;
}

#navbar img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#navbar ul {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transform: translateY(-400%);
}

#navbar li {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

#navbar-list li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#navbar-list li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid white;
}

/*Fim navbar*/
/*Banner*/
#main-banner {
    height: 80vh;
    background-image: url('Imgs/p3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 18vh;
}

#banner-infos {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#banner-infos img {
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 22%;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#banner-infos p {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

/*Fim Banner*/
/*About*/
#about-section {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 350px;
}

#about-section h2 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#about-section p {
    max-width: 650px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}

/*About*/
/*Skills*/
#skills-section {
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 85%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1.7px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#skills-section .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.skills-container {
    flex: 1 1 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 25px;
    ;
}

.central {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.skills-container h3 {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.skills-container img {
    height: 105px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    border-right: 5.5px solid #000000;
}

.skills-container .subtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.skills-container p {
    line-height: 25px;
}

/*Fim Skills*/


/*Products*/
#products-section {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#products-section h2 {
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#products-section p {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#products-section a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(220 151 19);
}

.product-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-box {
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.pr1 {
    background-image: url('Imgs/p1.jpg');
}

.pr2 {
    background-image: url('Imgs/p2.jpg');
}

.pr3 {
    background-image: url('Imgs/p6.jpg');
}

/*Fim Products*/
/*Footer*/
footer {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

footer img {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px 0;

}

footer p {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

footer form {
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

footer input,
footer textarea {
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

footer .desenvolvedor {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*Fim Footer*/

/*Responsivo para smartphone*/
@media (max-width: 991px) {

    p,
    input,
    textarea,
    #navbar-list li a {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    #navbar h2 {
        /*visibility: hidden;*/
        display: none;
    }
    
    /*==| Você colocou um transform translate no menu |==*/
    
    #navbar ul {
      transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
    /*==| Você colocou um transform translate no menu |==*/

    #navbar ul {
        margin-top: 1.1rem;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>The Gallery Art - XXI</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-widht, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilo.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <header id="navbar">
      <img src="Imgs/Logo.png" alt="#" />
      <h2 class="titulo-desktop">Esse texto tem que sumir no smartphone</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul id="navbar-list">
        <!--Essas três opções tem que continuar-->
          <li><a href="##">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="##">Conteúdo</a></li>
          <li><a href="##">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Fim Navbar-->

    <main>
      <!--Banner-->
      <div id="main-banner">
        <div id="banner-infos">
          <h1>X X I</h1>
          <img src="Imgs/Logo.png" alt="#" />
          <p>
            The risk of a wrong decision is preferable to the terror of
            indecision....
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Fim Banner-->
      <!--About-->
      <section id="about-section">
        <h2>The 21st Century Digital Art Revolution</h2>
        <p>
          The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced
          below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de
          Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their
          exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914
          translation by H. Rackham.
        </p>
      </section>
      <!--Fim About-->
    </main>

    <!--Skills-->
    <section id="skills-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills-container">
          <img src="Imgs/1.png" alt="Img1" />
          <h3>Teste</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry.
          </p>
          <p class="subtitle">Zeus</p>
          <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
          </p>

          <p class="subtitle">Hera</p>
          <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-container">
          <img src="Imgs/2.png" alt="Img2" />
          <h3>The Concept</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Poseidon</p>
          <p>
            Curabitur urna leo, malesuada at dolor et, interdum convallis
            lectus.
          </p>
          <p class="subtitle">Atena</p>
          <p>Ut aliquam facilisis nibh vitae convallis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-container">
          <img src="Imgs/3.png" alt="Img3" />
          <h3>The Purpouse</h3>
          <p>Ut vulputate neque ut lacus suscipit ullamcorper</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Ares</p>
          <p>Ut nunc mi, pharetra eu eleifend vitae, gravida ac lacus.</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Apolo</p>
          <p>Nulla interdum lectus quam, malesuada luctus ex viverra eu.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--Fim Skills-->
    <!--Products-->
    <section id="products-section">
      <h2>Artwork of the week</h2>
      <p>
        Check out some of the featured artworks, or click
        <a href="#">here</a> and see them all.
      </p>
      <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-box pr1"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr2"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-container">
        <div class="product-box pr2"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr3"></div>
        <div class="product-box pr1"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--Fim Products-->
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <p>We await your message :)</p>
      <img src="Imgs/Logo.png" alt="#" />

      <form action="" method="">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <!--INPUT PARA NUM DE TELEFONE-->
        <input type="tel" name="number" placeholder="Number" />
        <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Done!" />
      </form>
      <p>Developer <span class="desenvolvedor">Gustavo Lopes - 2021</span></p>
    </footer>
    <!--Fim Footer-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!